# Flask Url_for with dynamic file name

Tags: flask

I'm running into issues with Flask caching my bundle.js file despite setting `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` when I'm running webpack in watch mode, so I've decided to add a build version to my `bundle.js` in an effort to break the browser cache.

Presently, I have:

`<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='bundle.js')}}"></script>`

in my html file and I'll need to add a variable to it. The problem is I don't know what the version will be, so is there a way to grab the file name in flask, and send it in with my render_template? I imagine something like: `<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='bundle{}.js'.format(version))}}"></script>`

and then grabbing the version from app.py by looking in the static folder for a file that begins with bundle, has an integer, and ends with .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.py file:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['js_bundle_file'] = 'bundle-1.1.js'
```

In your template:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename=js_bundle_file)}}"></script>
```

Instead of hardcoding your bundle file, you could also look for it using a slightly hacky list comprehension:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['js_bundle_file'] = [f for f in os.listdir('static') if f.endswith('.js') and f.startswith('bundle')][0]
```

or this cleaner looking glob:

```
import glob
app.jinja_env.globals['js_bundle_file'] = glob.glob('static/bundle*.js')[0]
```